# trouble executing script in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am completely new to scripting, so take it easy on me, thanks. I use the command `bash greetings2` and receive

```
greetings2: line 17: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
greetings2: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

```bash
#
# greetings2
# greetings program version 2
# A sample program using the if-then-elif construct
# This program displays greetings according to the time of day
# Version2: using the date command format control option
#
echo                   # skip a line
hour=`date +%H`        # store the part of the date string that shows the hour
if [ "$hour" -le 18 ]  # check for the morning hours
then
    echo "GOOD MORNING"
elif [ "$hour -le 18 ] # check for the afternoon hours
then
     echo "GOOD AFTERNOON"
else                   #it must be evening
    echo  "GOOD EVENING"
fi
echo                   # skip a line
exit 0                 # end of the program, exit
```

Comment: Paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and receive enlightment!

Answer (score 0):

your script has CRLF line termination (Windows style).
Convert it with `d2u filename` to LF line termination (Unix style)

`d2u` belongs to `dos2unix` package

To verify you can use

```
$ file greetings2
greetings2: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ d2u greetings2
dos2unix: converting file greetings2 to Unix format...

$ file greetings2
greetings2: ASCII text
```

Comment: hey matzeri, I am confused, is there another way to explain it?